# How can I take into account shared posts in a Neo4j newsfeed?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have linked lists of `POSTS` connected with `NEXT` relationships for every `FRIEND` of a specific `USER` NODE:

USER->[:STATUS]->POST->[:NEXT]->POST->[:NEXT]->POST->[:NEXT]->POST

I can retrieve the most recent 15 posts from a users friends like so:

```
MATCH (me:USER { userid: 'John.Smith' })-[rels:FRIEND*0..1]-(myfriend)                
MATCH (myfriend)-[:STATUS]-(latestupdate)-[:NEXT*0..15]-(statusupdates)
RETURN statusupdates, myfriend
ORDER BY statusupdates.time DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 15
```

Now, some of these posts 'might' be shares of other `POSTS` which are stored elsewhere in the graph.  In order to keep feed retrieval simple, we are denormalizing somewhat and are storing the `post_id` of the shared post on the new `POST` in these linked lists.

Therefore, occasionally a users friends will have shared the same post, resulting in several of the returned `statusupdates` having the same `share` id/property.  Such results get aggregated at the application level (John, Jane and Sarah shared this post)

But this will of course mean that sometimes retrieving 15 results does `not` result in 15 actual newsfeed items.  Since several items end up getting aggregated in to one.

My first instinct was to simply ensure that the `LIMIT` clause in the above query is increased by the number of share properties found in the result-set, so that we still end up with 15 individual newsfeed items (affter app level aggregation) when enough are available.

For example:

If we have 4 posts all with the same `share` id, and another 2 posts with another `share` id and all rest have no share property at all, then we need to add add (4+2) or 6 onto the `LIMIT` clause.

Unfortunately, it appears as though the `LIMIT` clause cannot use variables, so simply counting the occurrences of `share` properties and increasing the `LIMIT` is a no go.

How can I best handle this?

Can Neo4J do this kind of aggregation, before limiting the results?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider an [:ORIGIN] relationship from any shared post to the original post. That can let you perform aggregation with respect to original posts, and collect the friends of those who have shared/posted them. Something like this (have not tested):

```
MATCH (me:USER { userid: 'John.Smith' })-[rels:FRIEND*0..1]-(myfriend)                
MATCH (myfriend)-[:STATUS]-(latestupdate)-[:NEXT*0..15]-(statusupdates)-[:ORIGIN*0..1]->(origin)
RETURN origin, COLLECT(myFriend) as friends, MAX(statusupdates.time) as time
ORDER BY time DESC SKIP 0 LIMIT 15
```

If it was an original post by a friend, origin will be the same as the statusupdate (no origin relationship, so the statusupdate itself is returned as the origin), and only one friend will be in the collection.

If it was a post shared by several friends, the origin will be the original post, the friends collection will include all friends who shared the post.

In the case where one friend posted the original, and another friend shared it, it will be useful to know the person who posted the original. That's something you could easily add into the query, or you could simply return the original poster id and look for that match in the application layer.

Comment: Thanks.  How would this method compare performance wise, to our current one? Baring in mind that we will also be checking for likes etc in this query and need it to be queried in real-time at scale.

Comment: Just to explain, we were trying to take advantage of the fact that for other reasons, we are only storing relationships in Neo4j, with all actual post data being stored in DynamoDB. We collect all the post id's and share id's and do a quick lookup in DynamoDB to get the data before aggregating and sticking it all together.  The intention being to keep traversals during the newsfeed reads to an absolute minimum.  We were still intending on linking the post nodes with a [:ORIGIN] relationship, just not using it during this query.

Comment: For best results, you'll want to do your own PROFILE tests on this one (easy enough if the :ORIGIN relationship was already planned), but I wouldn't expect the alteration to affect the speed very much, as it's just a single extra traversal per statusupdate, and it won't be emitting any additional rows.

Comment: You say it's only a single extra traversal per statsupdate, but with 1000 friends, wouldn't that be 15,000 extra traversals for every read? (We are currently collecting the 15 latest posts from each friend) Is there any way to check for the existence of an [:ORIGIN] relationship as we traverse the linked list, without actually fanning out to them? (there can only ever be one [:ORIGIN] per post)  And then only collecting the actual origin posts, if they exist, after the result set has been limited?

Comment: You could check for the existence of an origin node by either looking for that relationship itself while matching on the statusupdates, but I would think that would cost about as much as the actual traversal, so I doubt you would save anything that way. Besides, aggregating with respect to the origin nodes is what allows you to get the proper matching counts in your limit, so you can't really do that after the limit. Keep in mind also that this won't emit more rows than your original query, and that nodes here are more like pointers to nodes. Node property access is where things get expensive.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do what you want:

```
MATCH (me:USER { userid: 'John.Smith' })-[rels:FRIEND]-(myfriend)                
MATCH (myfriend)-[:STATUS|NEXT*..16]-(statusupdates)
WITH statusupdates, myfriend
ORDER BY statusupdates.time DESC
WITH REDUCE(s = {ids:[], res:[]}, x IN COLLECT({statusupdates: statusupdates, myfriend: myfriend}) |
  CASE
    WHEN SIZE(s.ids) < 15 THEN
      CASE
        WHEN x.statusupdates.post_id IS NULL THEN
          CASE
            WHEN x.statusupdates.id IN s.ids THEN
                 {ids: s.ids, res: s.res + x}
            ELSE {ids: s.ids + x.statusupdates.id, res: s.res + x}
          END
        WHEN x.statusupdates.post_id IN s.ids THEN
             {ids: s.ids, res: s.res + x}
        ELSE {ids: s.ids + x.statusupdates.post_id, res: s.res + x}
      END
    ELSE s
  END) AS out
UNWIND out.res AS result
RETURN result;
```

The logic returns at most 15 unique update ids, allowing for the same id to be referenced multiple times. It assumes that all updates have a unique `id` property and an optional `post_id` property that references another update. The `REDUCE` clause will only put an update's `id` in the `ids` collection if it does not have a `post_id` property (and it is not already in the collection), otherwise it will put the `post_id` value in the collection (if it is not already there). As long as the size of the `ids` collection is less than 15, it will add each update/myfriend pair to the `res` collection; and after the max size is reached it will leave the collections unchanged.

Note that the `[rels:FRIEND*0..1]` syntax in your original query will also return the posts by `me`, which does not seem to agree with what you said you wanted. If you truely just want the friends' posts, use `[rels:FRIEND]` instead, as I did in my query.

Comment: Thanks cybersam.  While this definitely more directly answers my actual question, before I consider switching to award you the answer, would you mind commenting on this approach as opposed to the more basic relationship/graph modelling one proposed by InverseFalcon? Particularly with regards to feed reading performance.  There appears to be a lot more work going on here.  Would it still perform better than fanning out to [:ORIGIN] nodes?

Comment: @gordyr If the data is already modeled, PROFILING all applicable queries is your best bet to determine performance. Honestly I'm quite curious myself. My guess is that property access might slow this one, but I'm always looking to improve my cypher knowledge, and see where iteration with REDUCE beats out pattern matching and aggregation.